# How to dim a parent UIView (50% transparent) for login?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoa-touch

I have a view with a Login button. When the button is clicked, I add a view with fields for login. When this happens, I need to dim the parent view. How I do that?

Comment: Wow...going to need a little more information than this...  What classes are you working with?  What exactly do you mean by "dim the...view"?

Comment: I would add a view that's got a black background with 50% alpha, then stick another view in that with the bg color that I want to display, with the text fields and labels and whatnot inside.

Comment: @Gerep glad it helped, but you should be clearer in what you need in the future for real answers... I was just shooting in the dark.

Comment: Wouldn't a Modal View Controller be appropriate here?  See apple's View Controller Programming Guide for IOS : Modal View Controllers.

Comment: @ditkin: probably not, modal view controllers can't be (partly) transparent in a useful way. If you'd choose to make the view inside a modal view controller (partly) transparent, you'd see a white background.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add a UIView over the parent view that is initially transparent with a background color of black. When you need to dim it, change the view's alpha to 0.5. This will be 50% transparent.

Comment: As this question continues to get attention. Keep in mind that this answer is not the best option as of this time , adds more complexity to the view hierarchy, and includes extra effort, and probably introduced auto layout issues as it has to be handled manually, probably also performance issues. 

UIView hierarchy already has a property for this.

Answer (score 14):

`UIViews` have a property named `mask`.

`mask` will always be on top of the **UIView** who owns it.

So, your approach should be something like this:

*(This is for Swift, but it's easily converted to Obj-c)*

```
self.view.mask = UIView(frame: self.frame)
self.view.mask?.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.5)

//Do your work here, block UI, anything you need to, and then...
self.view.mask = nil
```

> **Update**
>
> - Removed Swift 2 refernce as it's not relevant anymore. Just as a curiosity, then the property was called `maskView`

Answer (score 4):

I would go for a view with white background:

```
whiteView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:viewToDim.frame];
[whiteView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[whiteView setAlpha:0.5f];
[self.view insertSubview:whiteView aboveSubview:viewToDim];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class UIDecorator: NSObject {

    static let sharedInstance = UIDecorator()
    private let dimView = UIView()
    private let loadingView = MOOverWatchLoadingView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100),
                                                             autoStartAnimation: true)
    func showLoadingView() {
        if let currentPage = UIApplication.topViewController(){
            dimView.frame = currentPage.view.frame
            dimView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
            dimView.alpha = 0.5
            currentPage.view.addSubview(dimView)
            currentPage.view.userInteractionEnabled = false
            loadingView.center = currentPage.view.center
            loadingView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
            currentPage.view.addSubview(loadingView)
        }
    }

    func dismissLocadingView() {
        if let currentPage = UIApplication.topViewController(){
            currentPage.view.userInteractionEnabled = true
            dimView.removeFromSuperview()
            loadingView.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
}
```